# API csv Import - Error when importing activities "Invalid value for field (activity_type_id) "

Tags: import

Trying to import new activities using API cvs Import. I'm using the ID from the link to edit a custom activity type, like this www.mysite/civicrm/admin/options/activity_type?action=update&id=***1028***&reset=1

But keep getting this error, any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Import worked fine once I matched the activity name with the activity type ID field.